# Django - Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

I got an error:

```
TypeError at /cart/
Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

The fact is that I store my favorites and the basket in the same session, and when one of these is not filled (favorites / basket), this error appears.
When the products are in both lists everything is fine.

```
allow_nan   
    True
    check_circular  
    True
    cls 
    <class 'json.encoder.JSONEncoder'>
    default 
    None
    ensure_ascii    
    True
    indent  
    None
    kw  
    {}
    obj 
    {'cart': {'2': {'price': Decimal('123123.12'),
                    'product': <Product: test1>,
                    'quantity': 2,
                    'total_price': Decimal('246246.24'),
                    'update_quantity_form': <CartAddProductForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(quantity;update)>}},
     'favorites': {}}
    separators  
    (',', ':')
    skipkeys    
    False
    sort_keys   
    False
```

If I add product in favorites and remove items from the cart, I already get this error

```
TypeError at /favorites/
Object of type Product is not JSON serializable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/favorites/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type Product is not JSON serializable
Exception Location: E:\Python\lib\json\encoder.py, line 179, in default
```

There is the cart code:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from main.models import Product


class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):

        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)

        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):

        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):

        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        if quantity == 0:
            del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):

        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def get_total_price(self):

        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):

        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

cart/views.py:

```
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from main.models import Product, OrderItems, Order
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm, OrderForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    cart.add(product=product,
             quantity=1,
             update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    form = OrderForm()
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'update': True})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = Order(data_time=datetime.date.today(),
                     user=request.user.username,
                     total_cost=cart.get_total_price())
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            data.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItems.objects.create(Order=order,
                                          Product=item['product'],
                                          Price=item['price'],
                                          Quantity=item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'main/cart.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

cart/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/',
         views.cart_add,
         name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/',
         views.cart_remove,
         name='cart_remove'),
]
```

Favorites are same, but with no quantity and price:

```
from django.conf import settings
from main.models import Product


class Favorites(object):

    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        favorites = self.session.get(settings.FAVORITES_SESSION_ID)
        if not favorites:
            favorites = self.session[settings.FAVORITES_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.favorites = favorites

    def __len__(self):
        Fsum = 0
        for item in self.favorites.values():
            Fsum += 1
        return Fsum

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.favorites.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        favorites = self.favorites.copy()
        for product in products:
            favorites[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
        for item in favorites.values():
            yield item

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.favorites:
            del self.favorites[product_id]
            self.save()

    def add(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.favorites:
            self.favorites[product_id] = {}
        else:
            del self.favorites[product_id]
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.FAVORITES_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

views.py and urls.py are the same as in the cart

I also used different SESSION_ID for each

And i have context_processors.py:

```
from .cart import Cart


def cart(request):
    return {'cart': Cart(request)}
```

favorites context processors are the same

This is how I display them:

```
  <div class="catalog__wrap">
    <div class="catalog__items items" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemList">
        {% for item in featured %}
            {% with product=item.product %}
                <div class="item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Product" data-element-id="21977">
                    <img class="item__img" itemprop="image" src="{{ product.multiple_images.first.images.url}}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                    <div class="item__info">
                        <h3 class="item__name">{{ product.name }}</h3>
                            <div class="item__offers" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
                                <p class="item__price item__price">
                                Опт <span class="item__sum" itemprop="price">{{ product.price }} ₽</span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="item__price item__price--red">
                                Розница <span class="item__sum" itemprop="price">{{ product.price }} ₽</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <div class="item__buttons">
                        <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                        <button class="item__buy" type="submit" data-modal="sizes" style="width: 95px; height: 40px">В корзину</button>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        </form>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="item__link" itemprop="url" href="{% url 'product_page' product.cat.slug product.slug %}" title="{{ product.name }}"></a>
                </div>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You are using `Decimal('123123.12')` which causes the error. `Decimal` is good for doing decimal math in python, but its not generally applicable to other languages. In particular, its not a standard JSON value. How to fix the problem depends on who you expect to consume the data. Normally, you'd just use a float (`123123.12`) and skip `Decimal` completely because float _is_ a JSON type and everybody understands it.

Comment: but as i said before, if there are products in the cart and in the featured at the same time, then everything works fine. For example, if I leave the cart empty and add a product to featured, it won't be able to display it because it can't serialize the product object

Comment: you have to convert `Decimal` to `string` before adding to JSON. And when you read JSON then you have to convert `string` to `Decimal` again.

Comment: JSON can keep only primitive types of data - int, float, string, list, dict. Other objects like `Decimal` and `Product` you have to convert to strings before adding to JSON, and later you have to convert strings  back to objects when you read JSON - and this need to write own code.

Comment: @furas Okay, but then why do they work if the products are added in cart and favorites at the same time?

Comment: you didn't show code so I can't run it to confim if it runs as you expect - maybe it runs some `if/else` and it runs different code.

Comment: We don't know the logic of your code, but any time it puts a Decimal in the data structure, you'll get this error. The answer is to not put Decimal in the data structure. Or write custom encoders and decoders to handle them. But that's usually suboptimal because it makes your web site less generic.

Comment: I added the source code, now you can see it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return render(request, 'main/cart.html', {'cart': json.dumps(cart,cls=DjangoJsonEncoder), 'form': form})
```